# If $f=g$ on $(x-r,x+r)\cap (0,1)$ and $g$ is Borel measurable, then $f$ is Borel measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

**Question**

Let $f:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that for every $x\in (0,1)$, there exists $r>0$ and a Borel measurable function $g$, both depending on $x$, such that $f$ and $g$ agree on $(x-r,x+r)\cap (0,1)$. Prove that $f$ is Borel measurable.

**Attempt**

For every $x\in (0,1)$ we may find an $r_x$ and a Borel measurable $g_x$ so that $f=g_x$ on $(x-r_x,x+r_x) \cap (0,1)$. Then $f=\sum_{x\in (0,1)}\chi_{(x-r_x,x+r_x) \cap (0,1)}g_x$ is Borel measurable. ($\chi$ is the characteristic function)

**Question**

I am wondering if my attempt is correct. Mostly I am concerned by the uncountable summation.

Comment: I would be concerned about the uncountable summation as well.

Comment: I felt that it was some how not uncountable.. But I couldn't find a lower bound on the interval length for each $x$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach that avoids the uncountable summation.

Let $I_n = [{1 \over n} , 1-{1 \over n}]$, which is compact. Find a finite covering $U_k$ of $I_n$ and measurable $g_k$ such that $f(x) = g_k(x)$ for $x \in U_k$. Let $V_1=U_1 \cap I_n$ and $V_{k} = (U_k \setminus (U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_{k-1})) \cap I_n$. Define $f_n = \sum g_k 1_{V_k}$ (a finite sum). Then $f_n$ is measurable and $f_n = f$ on $I_n$. Since $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in (0,1)$, we see that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Can we say that $\{x: f(x) \gt a\}=\cap_{q \in \left((0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}\right)}g_q^{-1}[(a,\infty)]$??

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam: Not really, for each $x$ the $g$ need only agree with $f$ locally.

Comment: Because for each such rational, we can find a neighborhood around it and a function which equals it in the neighborhood, I was wondering if $f$ can be defined by such functions

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam: We could manage an expression similar to what have, but each $g^{-1}$ would have to be 'pruned' by the range of equality of $f,g$. I think it is a little easier (for me!) to understand the approach in the answer.

Comment: Intuitively it seems to me that something like this might be true. But I can't give a proof. Should I make a question out of it?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam: That is your call. I think the expression would have to be a bit different than the one you have above.